# Find records by char on specific field's position - ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Consider we have a table `banners` with pseudo bitarray (bites saved as bytes, I know :) I use  them for storing 4 settings.

```
| name    | targeting |
+---------+-----------+
| banner1 | 1001      |
| banner2 | 0010      |
```

I want to search in table `banners` and find all records with "1" on 3rd position of targeting attribute.

### Working solution

I can do something like this

```
banners = []
Banner.all do |banner|
  banners << banner if banner.targeting[2] == "1"
end
```

### Better solution?

Would be better write own SQL query with SUBSTRING, or what do you suggest please?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a regular expression in mysql. Pretty sure the syntax is right but I haven't verified:

Banner.where("targeting REGEXP '^(2)' = '1'")

Comment: Hmm. Are you sure REGEXP '^(2)' is testing 2nd position to be "1"?

Comment: It's zero-based so 2 is testing position 3.